# On-Topic guidelines should be changed to include the same formatting as the flag and an Oxford comma

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, help-center, grammatical-correction

Based on the [discussion question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357879/1739000), https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic should have the debugging help paragraph changed to the following (adds Oxford comma and the italics from the corresponding flag to reduce ambiguity):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**")
>   must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error*,
>   and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question
>   itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not
>   useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and
>   Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Too bad I didn't have a list of three things in the title or it, too, could have had an oxford (serial) comma.

Comment: How about that: _On-Topic guidelines should be changed to include the same formatting as the flag, an Oxford comma, and some noise at the end._

Comment: Sometimes I wish these things were hosted somewhere where we could just submit pull requests, but I also really wouldn't want to be the person who has to review all the pull requests.