# Does Stack Overflow prose use Oxford commas?

Tags: support, grammatical-correction

Does page prose in the Stack Overflow website use [Oxford commas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)?

I'm asking because the description text for the "Review > Triage" queue is lacking an Oxford comma, and this feels off to me. (I think "found, understood and answered" should be "found, understood, and answered".)

[image: Review / Triage description]

Based on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357879/if-a-question-asks-why-an-error-is-occurring-is-it-necessary-to-provide-the-des) and my own recollection, I think Stack Overflow uses Oxford commas, but I'm not sure, and I'd like to hear an official/consensus answer.

Note: This question is not about content in questions, answers, or comments; just about the page text from Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 10):

> ### Commas
>
> Use the oxford comma in sentences. Don’t use a comma to separate two distinct phrases (comma splicing). Use two sentences instead.

source: https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics#commas

Comment: I can't fathom why this would be downvoted - except for the "oxford" being quoted without "(sic)" - given that it appears to directly answer the question, and quotes from the actual Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: This is true but most of the text on the site predates this standard and a couple of the people who write the text are anti-Oxford comma so... yeah. It's a bit of a mishmash.

Comment: @Catija well, then I wouldn't include it in the style guidelines. Only when you decide on something and everyone is onboard with it, then set that as a guideline. Is better a minimalist guideline that everyone follows rather than an all encompassing that everyone has objection to it. Humans tend to reject something on its entirety if they disagree with part of it.

Comment: But they have misspelt *[Oxford comma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Oxford_comma)*...

Comment: Oh, it's definitely the rule moving forward but we haven't updated the historical strings. I'm pretty sure that we're following it since it was rolled out (only about 6 months ago).

Comment: Heheh: There's a grammar issue on the Grammar and Mechanics guideline page. ("Ellipses" is plural; singular should be "ellipsis".) Anyone know where I can report that? Ask another Meta question?